# Update placeholder display when the value was changed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, orchardcms, placeholder

I have a page set up with Orchard CMS.  The problem I found was that I couldn't set a placeholder value for the text area of a contact form.  So I tried to fix it using the following:

```
@using(Script.Head()) {
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    function setPlaceholder() {
        document.getElementById("ContactForm_Message_Text").setAttribute("placeholder", "Message");
    }
    window.onload = setPlaceholder;
    </script>
}
```

This works to a degree, but the textarea only updates the placeholder when I click on the text area.  Is there a trick to fix this, or am I addressing it incorrectly?

Comment: You can fake focus the field to update the placeholder.

Comment: This works.  I added `document.getElementById("ContactForm_Message_Text").focus();`, but would prefer if it wasn't left with focus.  I tried shifting it after, but didn't work.  Good fix for now, but other ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant way to do this is changing the value after update the `placeholder`.This will force the DOM to Update the **textarea**. You can see the result here:

HERE: [jsfiddle for placeholder dynamically changed](http://jsfiddle.net/fals/4g2xp/)

```
function setPlaceholder() {       
  document.getElementById("ContactForm_Message_Text").setAttribute("placeholder", "Message");
  document.getElementById("ContactForm_Message_Text").value = "";
}
```

Comment: The problem is, it works without the setting the value to "". See http://jsfiddle.net/4g2xp/1/.  I think it's an issue Orchard is having.  It's a clean and elegant way to update the display if needed though.